# Allocate the unused/idle/completed threads in multi-thread processes in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

I am building a service that inquires data from multiple services, those services are all independent, so I can send the requests altogether at once to make the processing time efficient. Here is how I make the service launch multiple threads to do all at once:

```java
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        CompletionService completionService =
                new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);

        List<Future<Map>> res = new ArrayList<>();
        res.add(completionService.submit(() -> callAPI(HttpMethod.GET, "/inquiry1", null, null, null)));
        res.add(completionService.submit(() -> callAPI(HttpMethod.GET, "/inquiry2", null, null, null)));
        res.add(completionService.submit(() -> callAPI(HttpMethod.GET, "/inquiry3", null, null, null)));
        res.add(completionService.submit(() -> callAPI(HttpMethod.GET, "/inquiry4", null, null, null)));
        res.add(completionService.submit(() -> callAPI(HttpMethod.GET, "/inquiry5", null, null, null)));

        Map responseMap = new HashMap();
        for (int i=0; i < res.size(); i++) {
            try {
                responseMap.put("result_"+i, (Map) completionService.take().get());
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw (Exception) e.getCause();
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();
```

This actually gets the output as expected when all the dependency APIs goes well:

```json
{
    "result_1": {...},
    "result_2": {...},
    "result_3": {...},
    "result_4": {...},
    "result_5": {...}
}
```

However, when any dependency API needs longer processing time (or even having gateway timeout problem), the other threads are waiting for it even though the other processes are already done. And when there are many requests flooded this service, as it keeps opening 5 new threads and they are waiting for response from any slow dependency API, it made the instance crashes.

Therefore, my questions are:

1. How to make the threads closed or allocated to another process automatically when the process finishes (when it received response from dependency API and got the value stored in memory) ?
2. How to set threshold of the number of threads can be opened and make the service checks whether the process can be continued or just cut it off before opening the multi threads?

Comment: Don't create an `ExecutorService`, inject a `TaskExecutor` or rather `AsyncTaskExecutor` from Spring and use that. Configure one with a `ThreadPool` so that you reuse the threads. You should join the results together as now you are making the calls basically blocking (by iterating and calling get). This would also a nice one to do with Reactive programming and zipping the results together (would use less resources in high concurrent environments) but can take some time to get used to.

Comment: Do u mean changing the line `ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)` to `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor(); executor.setCorePoolSize(5);`? @M.Deinum

Comment: No. Create a bean for the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and inject it. Don't shut it down just reuse, that way you will always have that number of threads for use (you can scale using a larger max size and a moderate queue size).

Comment: @M.Deinum Could you please give the answer and example in the answer section of it? What if the traffic goes high at the moment but gets lower after that, wouldn't those opened threads just idle with constant resource usage (same as when traffic is high) over time during low traffic?

Comment: No as there are x threads.. In your case you will have 5 threads per request, in this case you will only have minimal 5 (and whatever you set as the max) instead of 5 per request.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will create 5 threads for each time the service method is being called.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
```

This creates a thread pool with 5 threads for each call. If you call it 100 times you have 100 * 5 = 500 threads. They are only used once and not recycled as you are closing the pool in each method.

As you are using Spring I suggest to use the `TaskExecutor` or rather `AsyncTaskExecutor` and configure it with a dynamic thread pool (min size 5 max, whatever you like, and a reasonable queue size). That way you will only have the number of threads you have specified as max (and it will eventually scale down depending on your configuration).

You should define this `TaskExecutor` as a bean in your configuration (or use the Spring Boot configured one) and inject this in your service to use it.

```java
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
  ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
  executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
  executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
  executor.setQueueCapacity(16);
  return executor;
}
```

Then in your service use this.

```java
public class YourService {

  private final AsyncTaskExecutor executor;

  public YourService(AsyncTaskExecutor executor) {
    this.executor=executor;
  }

  public Map getResponse()

    List<Future<Map>> res = new ArrayList<>();
    res.add(executor.submit(() -> callAPI(HttpMethod.GET, "/inquiry1", null, null, null)));
    res.add(executor.submit(() -> callAPI(HttpMethod.GET, "/inquiry2", null, null, null)));
    res.add(executor.submit(() -> callAPI(HttpMethod.GET, "/inquiry3", null, null, null)));
    res.add(executor.submit(() -> callAPI(HttpMethod.GET, "/inquiry4", null, null, null)));
    res.add(executor.submit(() -> callAPI(HttpMethod.GET, "/inquiry5", null, null, null)));

    Map responseMap = new HashMap();
    for (int i=0; i < res.size(); i++) {
      try {
        responseMap.put("result_"+i, (Map) completionService.take().get());
                
        } catch (Exception e) {
          throw (Exception) e.getCause();
        }
    }
    return responseMap;
}
```

Something like this. This will atmost have 10 threads active instead of 5 per request and reuse the created threads for creating the tasks.

Comment: I use the `@Autowired ThisService thisService` to call the service instance on controller. Can it apply the `AsyncTaskExecutor` and apply the bean `taskExecutor()`?

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding how beans work. It will just inject the taskexec utor created by the `taskExecutor` method (assuming it is an `@Bean` method).

Comment: Do you mean that by putting the `taskExecutor()`  Bean inside the class with `@Configuration` makes it automatically applies on every classes having that `AsyncTaskExecutor`?

Comment: Yes that is the whole point of having beans and use Spring to inject them.